# OwlCarousal Camera Slider owl item image, how do you change positioning left right center?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, owl-carousel

Can someone with experience with owlCarousal Camera slider in jquery help me on this. I want to show on mobile different starting point of the image or owl-item in the slider. Right now, it is just showing more left oriented, I want to move the whole image to slide more from right side. I tried with some options on the slider margin-left and transform-scale, but they are just moving the whole sliders instead the image positions, can someone help me how I can do on owlCarousal items or image?

also please find the attachments of output that I want to show on mobile, so I wanna show half bed looking on mobile, and for that, I need to move the slider image to start from different position, any help with CSS or owlCarousal javascript? :-
[![imageoutput][1]][1]
[![imageoutputex][2]][2]

````
style = "transform: translate3d(-8560px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 13268px;" > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-08.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-09.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-10.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-11.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-12.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-13.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-14.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-15.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-01.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-02.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-03.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-04.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-05.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-06.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-07.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-08.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-09.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-10.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-11.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item animated owl-animated-out fadeOut"
style = "width: 428px; left: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-12.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item active"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-13.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-14.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-15.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-01.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-02.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-03.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-04.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-05.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-06.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-07.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-item cloned"
style = "width: 428px;" > < div > < img src = "image/catalog/Slider/slide-08.jpg"
alt = "Slider" > < /div></div > < /div></div > < div class = "owl-nav disabled" > < button type = "button"
role = "presentation"
class = "owl-prev" > < span aria - label = "Previous" > ‹ < /span></button > < button type = "button"
role = "presentation"
class = "owl-next" > < span aria - label = "Next" > › < /span></button > < /div><div class="owl-dots disabled"></div > < /div>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxJjd.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0azB2.png
````